# How can an adventurer traveling using the Astral Projection spell have their silver cord cut?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, astral

The *Astral Projection* spell allows you to travel to the Astral Plane, where you are invulnerable... unless someone cuts your silver cord. Some effects that allow this are the githyanki knight's silver longsword, and the astral dreadnought's Sever Silver Cord trait, both of which allow them to cut silver cords on a crit. However, *Adamantine Armor* can mitigate this.

What other ways can a character traveling using the *Astral Projection* spell have their cord cut?

I'm looking for a list of official monsters and other hazards that can sever cords in order to build a character who is as invincible as possible on the Astral Plane. (I already am aware that you need to make sure nobody can find your body on the Material Plane.)

Comment: [This same question for 3.5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98128/48191)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### All known methods of severing a silvery cord involve a critical hit.

Besides the githyanki knight and the astral dreadnaught, the githyanki supreme commander also possesses the ability to sever a silvery cord on a critical hit.

Finally, *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* contains a writeup for a *greater silver sword* magic item, which can be attuned to and used by any "creature that has psionic ability." Any creature using this sword can sever a silvery cord on a critical hit.

Addendum: There is a sentence in the DMG that states that "Only a few things can sever a traveler's silver cord, the most common being a psychic wind (described below)." But that description does not mention cord-severing at all. So it is possible that a DM reads that sentence and comes up with a way for a silvery cord to be severed by a psychic wind in a way that does not involve a critical hit. Thank you to Nobody the Hobgoblin for pointing this out.

Comment: There is a statement in the DMG that the psychic wind can sever the cord. It does not say how, and the effect tables for Psychic Wind have no such outcome. So I think you are technically right (and I upvoted you) but a DM might still decide that Psychic Wind will eventually kill the character, even when they are immune to crits.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin Good catch and I will update my answer. It is very interesting that it says that a psychic wind is the "most common" thing that can sever a cord, but then severing a cord is not one of the listed results on the psychic wind effects table. Almost like it was removed from the table at some point in the editing process, but they forgot to remove it from the earlier paragraph.